# Angular polyfill.js causing slow INP indicator performances

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, polyfills, lighthouse

I'm working on optimizing performances on an Angular (v16) app, and the INP metric is pretty bad.

The details are shown in the screenshot. Apparently the issue is caused by the polyfill.js file which is coming from Angular.

[image]

The event target is juste an image enclosed in an a tag, doing basic Angular routing :

```
            <a [routerLink]="'landing_main'|routerGenerate">
                <img
                    class="landing-header__logo-image"
                    kartableAsset
                    src="/assets/media/icons/kartable-logo.svg"
                    i18n-alt="@@header_kartable_logo_image"
                    alt="Logo Kartable"
                    width="110"
                    height="40"
                    kartableImgAlt
                    i18n-seoAlt="@@seo_header_kartable_logo_image"
                    seoAlt="Logo Kartable"
                >
            </a>
```

Not sure what I could do here...THanks for your help !

Various unsuccessful tries (removing the a tag,...).

Comment: We're still looking for the answer ourselves, but we noticed while working on our jquery based site that the script it shows in the tool is often just the last script it hits (or maybe it's the first) but not really necessarily the actual cause. Hope that helps.